# Angularjs method calling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have so many calculations that goes like the following but in each and every calculation, parameters are different. But the method is the same. How can I write a method in AngularJS so I can use that method every time I need to calculate instead of writing codes every time.

PS: var 'name' also differs from each calculations.

```
var entropy_less_than60 = -(w_less_than60_positive/w_less_than60)*Math.log2(w_less_than60_positive/w_less_than60) 
                        - ((w_less_than60 - w_less_than60_positive)/w_less_than60)*Math.log2((w_less_than60-w_less_than60_positive)/w_less_than60);
```

Comment: Not sure why is this question tagged as angularjs, as this seems like a general programming question (how to write reusable code). Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I wrote a method and called it. it said it's undefined.

Comment: *"I wrote a method and called it. it said it's undefined"* . Then show the full code that didn't work. This isn't a code writing service. the idea here is to help you fix your code

Answer (score 0):

Create an associative array object and pass it to the function

```
var obj = { 
   w_less_than60_positive : '', 
   w_less_than60: 59,
   ....
}
```

Set the literals in it through view or other methods and You can pass this obj here :

```
function Calculate(obj){
    obj.entropy_less_than60 = -(obj.w_less_than60_positive/obj.w_less_than60)*
    Math.log2(obj.w_less_than60_positive/w_less_than60)
    - ((obj.w_less_than60 - obj.w_less_than60_positive)/obj.w_less_than60)*Math.log2((obj.w_less_than60-obj.w_less_than60_positive)/obj.w_less_than60);
}
```

See the final value on console:

```
Console.log(obj.entropy_less_than60)
```